# How to handle functions with dynamic sets of parameters?

Tags: rust

Some libraries such as Bevy or Actix Web have functions which accept user defined functions with any amount of parameters.

Actix Web:

```
async fn fn1(path: web::Path<String>) -> impl Responder {
    // not important 
}

async fn fn2(_req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    // not important
}

let app = App::new()
    .route("/", web::get().to(fn2))
    .route("/{name}", web::get().to(fn1));
```

Bevy:

```
fn fn1(mut commands: Commands) {}
fn fn2(mut commands: Commands, time: Res<Time>) {}

App::new().add_system(fn1).add_system(fn2);
```

As you can see in both cases the functions `web::get().to(), add_system()` accept functions with dynamic number and types of parameters as their parameter. They're not macros. How can I achieve this? Is there a name for this? Thanks

Comment: It's not pretty... Bevy [docs](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.6.0/bevy/ecs/system/trait.SystemParamFunction.html)/[src](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/crates/bevy_ecs/src/system/function_system.rs#L514)

Comment: [promethia-27](https://github.com/promethia-27) wrote an online book on [this topic](https://promethia-27.github.io/dependency_injection_like_bevy_from_scratch/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since functions can implement traits, the solution is to define a trait that represents "can serve as callback function" and then manually implement it for every function arity up to some large number of arguments. In `actix`, this is done by having `.to(f)` take something implementing the `Handler` trait:

```rust
pub fn to<F, Args>(mut self, handler: F) -> Self
where
    F: Handler<Args>,
    Args: FromRequest + 'static,
    F::Output: Responder + 'static,
```

Where `Handler` is defined by:

```rust
pub trait Handler<Args>: Clone + 'static {
    type Output;
    type Future: Future<Output = Self::Output>;

    fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Future;
}
```

And implementations for function arities are created as follows:

````rust
/// Generates a [`Handler`] trait impl for N-ary functions where N is specified with a sequence of
/// space separated type parameters.
///
/// # Examples
/// ```ignore
/// factory_tuple! {}         // implements Handler for types: fn() -> R
/// factory_tuple! { A B C }  // implements Handler for types: fn(A, B, C) -> R
/// ```
macro_rules! factory_tuple ({ $($param:ident)* } => {
    impl<Func, Fut, $($param,)*> Handler<($($param,)*)> for Func
    where
        Func: Fn($($param),*) -> Fut + Clone + 'static,
        Fut: Future,
    {
        type Output = Fut::Output;
        type Future = Fut;

        #[inline]
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        fn call(&self, ($($param,)*): ($($param,)*)) -> Self::Future {
            (self)($($param,)*)
        }
    }
});

factory_tuple! {}
factory_tuple! { A }
factory_tuple! { A B }
factory_tuple! { A B C }
factory_tuple! { A B C D }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E F }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E F G }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E F G H }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E F G H I }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E F G H I J }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E F G H I J K }
factory_tuple! { A B C D E F G H I J K L }
````

Comment: [promethia-27](https://github.com/promethia-27) wrote an online book on [this topic](https://promethia-27.github.io/dependency_injection_like_bevy_from_scratch/).